# How to display whole records from database in Gridview and also do filteration using textbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

How to display whole records from database in Gridview and also do filteration using textbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are any number of ways to do this, and which way you approach the probelm might depend on a number of inter-related factors; How many records will reasonable be returned each time a user perfroms a search? Should the list by default load with ALL records, and only filter upon request, or should it load emply, and only return requested records? Under reasonable use conditions, will the DGV be loaded with the entire table contents, or only a few records, post-search?

These and other considerations may or may not impact how you decide to fill and perform your filtering operation.

THIS example is a pretty rudimentary approach, and does not employ some of the ADO.NET niceties such as DataSet, TableADapter, and such. Instead it performs the filtering as a beck-end operation, submitting a parameterized query and returning the result set as a DataTable, which can then be set directly as the data source for your DGV control. I will not be suprized if this opens an argument (i mean, debate) about the ways and means of retreiving data with ADO.NET . . .

Anyway, there are other options, and I cannot be certain what will be most practical and/or efficient, given my limited knowledge of your design. One example would be to retreive a fully populated DataTable as a Private Class Memeber of the form, and then perform DataView.RowFilter operations against it, using the output as the DataSource for your Grid. THis has pros and cons as well; primarily, it might be better for limited-size result sets, or for cases in which data Access against the back-end suffers performance bottlenecks.

A fianl note - my silly example here essentially refines the search each time the text in the Textbox changes. Depending upon your needs, you may want to set it up so that the search is not executed until the user presses a button, or the enter key.

NOTE: THis is just one example, and any code like this should be refined with exception handling, and adapted for the performance requirements of your design!

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim dgv As DataGridView = Me.DataGridView1
    Me.UpdateSearch("")

End Sub

'A Function which returns a DataTable, to be used as the DataSource for a DataGridView:
Private Function ClientsDataTable(ByVal SearchCriteria As String) As DataTable


    'The default popoulation of your Grid Control will determine how you 
    'contruct your SQL and/or set up you parameter(s); If you want it BLANK until the user enters a value in 
    'your textbox, you will need to modify some of the logic here . . . THIS extra-simple example
    'fills the DGV with ALL records in the table if no parameter (and empty String) is passed:
    Dim SQL As String = _
    "SELECT ClientID, LastName, FirstName " & _
    "FROM tblClient " & _
    "WHERE LastName Like @LastName & '%'"

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(My.Settings.CreateThisConnection)
        Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQL, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", SearchCriteria)

            cn.Open()
            Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(dr)
            dr.Close()
            cn.Close()
        End Using
    End Using

    Return dt

End Function

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Me.UpdateSearch(Me.TextBox1.Text.Trim)
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateSearch(ByVal SearchCriteria As String)
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = ClientsDataTable(SearchCriteria)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "whole records from the database", but if you want the ENTIRE row for each record, Use "SELECT * FROM TableName . . .  Etc" instead of "SELECT Field1, Field2 . . ."